# Can't add base64 public key in new version of billing service

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I'm trying to add in-app purchases in the app with

```
'com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1'
```

And I can't find a way to add base64 public key, generated by Google Play Console, in new billing library api.

How can I add public key?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New in-app billing library doesn't need base64 public key. You can still get base64 public key in google developer's console, but now there is no mentions in the docs how to use it.